# What mistake is there in solving the following determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
 1  & 0 & 3 \\ 
 5  & 1 & 1 \\ 
 0  & 1 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
I tried to use row-reduction to solve the determinant more easily, the following operations I did:
[image]

Now that it is a upper triangular matrix, I should be able to do $1\cdot (-1) \cdot 16 = -16$, however
the answer says it must be 16, so I am having a sign problem. As far as I know the operations that I do should not be influencing the determinant of the original matrix. What am I doing wrong here ? Thank you

Comment: You can *add* a multiple of one row to another row. You implicitly multiplied row 2 by $-1$ which changed the sign of the determinant.

Comment: Your error?  $5R_1\color{red}{-R_2}\mapsto R_2$.  It is not true that every elementary row operation leaves the determinant unchanged.  Only those row operations which involve adding a linear combination of **other** rows to the **original** row... you flipped the sign of $R_2$ there.  Instead, you could have done $-5R_1\color{blue}{+R_2}\mapsto R_2$ and been fine.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much guys, it is very good that I realize this kind of error that can be done. I understand my problem.

Comment: Just to be explicit, the point is that $5R_1-R_2\mapsto R_2$ is not an elementary row operation.

Comment: @YavuzBozkurt The key idea behind why elementary row operations preserve the determinant is as follows. The determinant is linear on each row, and because it is alternating, it takes any matrix with dependent rows to $0$. So let $A=(R_1,\ldots,R_n)$, where $R_1,\ldots, R_n$ are length $n$ vectors. Then, if I replace $R_j$ with $kR_i$, where $i\neq j$, then the determinant of that matrix is $0$. But by linearity, that tells us that the matrix $R_1,\ldots,R_{i-1},R_i+kR_j,R_{i+1},\ldots,R_n$ has the same determinant as $A$. Why does this not work with what you did?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why is  $5R_{1} - R_{2} -> R_{2}$ is not an elementary row operation I am confused ? I taught my mistake was due to violation of rule JMoravitz explained

Comment: It simply does not satisfy the definition of "elementary row operation". By definition there are three sorts of row ops: (i) swapping two rows (ii) multiplying a row by a non-zero scalar, (iii) replacing a row by itself plus a multiple of another row.

Comment: @YavuzBozkurt look at my comment.

Comment: @DonThousand I think the idea doesn't work because I "subtracted" while making the row operation, the properties say that the determinant only remains constant when addition is done, so subtraction might be influencing the determinant in this case I think.

Comment: @YavuzBozkurt That's a repeat of JMoravitz's comment. I'm asking for an explanation in terms of the determinant I gave you. I want to see if you actually understand it.